# How do I call to this link in a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, greasemonkey

The target HTML:

```html
 <a href="#" data-role="button" id="dispatchOnJobButton" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c" data-disabled="false">
 <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all" aria-hidden="true">
 <span class="ui-btn-text">Dispatch on next job
 </span>
 </span>
 </a>
```

I tried using `document.getElementById("dispatchOnJobButton").click();` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Also a side note that I'm using firefox.  .click() works on buttons in other tests, but not on a link apparently.  Is there some other way I could just call to it?

Answer (score 0):

The most robust way to click such links is to send a Mouse Event, like so:

```
var targLink    = document.getElementById ("dispatchOnJobButton");
var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
targLink.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
```

---

This works much more often than any other method, but some pages might trigger off of mouseovers and mousedowns (or otherwise block most attempts to trigger clicks).

Link to the target page or post fully-contained demonstration code, if the above does not work for your target page(s).